# Java 7 seemingly odd behavior with placement of empty string in debug message

Tags: java, debugging

I am noticing odd behavior, at least to me, in my program.

Incorrect output:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        while(count < 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Count: " + count);
            System.out.println("" +(count*2)+1);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Yields the following print statements:

```
Count: 1
21
Count: 2
41
```

Whereas this program:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        while(count < 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Count: " + count);
            System.out.println((count*2)+1 + "");
            count++;
        }
    }
```

yields this output:

```
Count: 1
3
Count: 2
5
```

My question is does Java 7 do something special when you put the empty string, `""`, at the front of a arithmetic expression that it does not do when the empty string follows that arithmetic expression?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `+` operator has two meanings.
`number + number` means addition; `string + anything` means string concatenation.

The `+` operator is left-associative.
Therefore, `"" + a + b"` is parsed as `("" + a) + b`

Comment: yes I understand that.  However that doesn't explain why string+number yields different output than number + string, at least to me

Comment: Because in the first case it creates a string and then add two numbers to it, while in the second case the sum of two numbers produce one number which is then transformed to string.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with brackets.

```
("" +(count*2)) + 1
```

and

```
(count*2 + 1) + ""
```

are not the same.

Comment: A similar puzzle is `System.out.println("test is null is " + text == null);`  prints `false` even if `text` is `null`